# Is this an example of an iOS UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, button, tableview

I need to do something like this :

[image]
 .

Is it a `UITableView`? Or how should I do this? Any idea is welcome.

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

       if (indexPath.row == 0) return cell1;

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

       if (indexPath.row == 0) return cell2;

    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {

       if (indexPath.row == 0) return cell3;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely its a *UITableView*. May be its not (it can be a *UIScrollView* with views added like sections in a table view).

But if you want to create something like in the image, I'd suggest you to use ***UITableView*** with customized cells. Because implementing table view, in this case, is simpler as you have to just concern about the *delegate* and the *dateSource* of the table view, rather than worrying about aligning the views in order.

Use ***sectioned table view*** with the *translucent, gray-bordered, black-background-view* as the *backgroundView* of the cells. Add the *labels* and *arrow* as the *subviews* of cell. You can add *arrow* as the ***accessoryView*** but that would become vertically centered, but in the image the arrow is displayed slightly on top of the cell.

There should be only one cell in each section.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 1;
}
```

There can be any number of sections (3 here).

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 3; // Can be any number
}
```

Comment: I made the cells, I inserted the label as subviews on cells, but it looks like this : http://i51.tinypic.com/2lsi3wj.png How can I separate the cells?

Comment: You should show each cells in different sections. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now I see only the first row like this : http://i56.tinypic.com/2mhvccg.png How can I set to make the row height bigger?

Comment: Return the height from `heightRowInSection` method.

Comment: I wrote this : - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 30;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    
    return 3; // Can be any number
}  and I obtain this : http://i51.tinypic.com/2qltweb.png ...Please help me..how to see all the rows?

Comment: The problem seems to be in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` post the code.

Comment: Yes. I have corrected the mistake in your code. Check it now!

Comment: I get program received exc_bad_access.

Comment: This should work. I don't have any idea why you get the exception!

Comment: With my initial code and some changes I get this : http://i55.tinypic.com/24yo8bb.png the rows appear on the screen and then they suddenly fade away.If I scroll appear at the bottom on the screen or at the top at the screen.Are never vissible at the middle of the screen.

Comment: Sorry man! It will be really hard to solve your problem without seeing your full code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3693/discussion-between-gabrielle-and-emptystack)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's most likely a styled table view. [See this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html) or [this nice tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-unique-looking-tables-with-custom-cells.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using tableView in

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{

//here place return your array contents

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you worry about this one? Its simple man.... its nothing ,if you have hands over UITableView. Yeah, You must know about :
1: Set background image on view,exact as table size. 
2: Set table view onto them and make background transparent.
3: Make customize table cell and add to table' row.

Thats it.....enjoy this work..its a creativity.
And you can do it guy....

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell exactly what is used from the picture, however I suggest using the **UITableView** especially if you have variable data coming from a structured object.

Some tutorials which I found very useful are the following:

Creating customized **UITableViewCell** from XIB
http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/

UIViewTable anti-patterns - A very good MVC pattern to build **UIViewTable**
http://www.slideshare.net/nullobject/uitableviewcontroller-antipatterns

And of course Apple's docs:
http:/developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

One important fact to remember is that ***you should always reuse cached table cells*** through the datasource method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

**Note:** Since you want lots of transparencies there might be some performance issue especially on older devices.

Hope this helps and goodluck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to its scrollview or tableview... both are perform same..

Just change the Background Color of Tableview as clear color.....

check this code...

put this line to viewDidLoad :

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

and

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

.....  // Your label buttons etc........
......
......
.....

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[cell setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[cell layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[cell layer] setCornerRadius:10];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish the similar as shown in image above by Table View and scroll view both.If you don't want to use table view then you can take a scroll view or a simple view and can add several buttons along with the image in background with different frames.It means button background will have the same image.then you can use different labels to show all the texts in different labels according to the requirement.
OR
you can use table view.For this you need to return number of sections 3(in this image) in the delegate method  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView.and then everything as the default tableview style.And then change the cell style to detailed.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a tableView with custom UITableViewCell.you can do that by creating a empty      xib file and then add a UITableViewCell and do your customizing ...then in   cellForRowAtIndexPath method use:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:edentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"yourCellName" owner:self   options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
```

this is from my application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a `groupedtableview` with `clearcolor` as `backgroundcolor`. Cell background color also needs to be changed to `clearcolor`.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using div or list, don't use table, its very hard to control if the contents are too long.